# Can't add two FK-related tables into maintenance view?

Tags: foreign-keys, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I created two database tables: **Primary table** and **Secondary table**.

An `Employer` field of `Primary table` is a foreign key for an `Employer` field for `Secondary table`, at least I see a checked checkbox at Secondary->Entry Help/Check for Employer field. Both tables are activated.

Now I'm trying to create a View and here is the problem. I choose *Dictionary  Objects->Create->View->choose Maintenance View*, then enter a name.

I go on and then at Table/Join Conditions I'm able to add only ONE table. Why not two? Also I see a blue hint "Table selection and join definition only possible with relationships".

What's the reason I can't add two tables to the View? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: It would really help if you added some screenshots describing the steps you are taking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check whether there really is a foreign key relation ship (key/arrow button above the columns of the secondary table).

When creating the view, the system should show you a message (don't know the english text,
should amount to "you can only add secondary views using the key relations"). Enter the primary table you want to maintain. Then place the cursor in that field and press the button below the list of tables. Select the other table from the list. If you don't see it there, chances are that your relationship definitions are wrong.

(This whole setup is to ensure that you only use relationship definitions that can be used by the view maintenance generator later on.)

Please [take a look at the documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6f3c662f6c4b1014b3c1f279a90f707f/7.01.22/en-US/cf21ed06446011d189700000e8322d00.html) as well, this should explain a lot of other questions you might encounter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution is: first I should add a Secondary table and then press the button Relationships to choose the filed from the Primary table. Now 2 tables are in the view. The question was solved. Thank you for your help in finding a solution!